# Firebase Audiences Not Working Properly?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

We are using Firebase Analytics on our Android App. We've created an audience called Uninstallers(who sends app_remove event more than 0 times) to make it possible to run remarketing campaigns for users who uninstalled our app. But we have realized that the Uninstallers audience does not include every user who sent app_remove event. What is wrong with Firebase Analytics?[image: Audience Definition]

[image: app_remove event count]

[image: Audience records contradicts with the event count]

Comment: AFAIK, this was a bug in Firebase Analytics in 2016. For one of my projects, I am experiencing same. So I think this bug is still not resolved by Firebase team.

Answer (score 1):

Audience definitions are fetched from the server and evaluated on the device. There are multiple reasons: Audience results may not correspond to the number of events. The audience number depends on multiple factors (mostly number of devices). If you install and uninstall the app, it may not be the same with different users due to other factors. So you may see 33 events, but some might come from the same devices. Another reason may be at the time the event is uploaded, the newer audience definition has not been fetched so the audience result is not evaluated and sent to the server.